# What uniquely identifies a procedure in the Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I need to implement a program that compares databases. The problem I am currently facing is the question of stored procedures' identifier.

For example, using `DatabaseMetaData` interface from Oracle one can specify a tuple of catalog, schema and procedure name. Are these three columns enough to uniquely identify a procedure?

What about procedures that are part of a package? If I had these would it be possible to have two procedures with the same catalog, schema and name? Would both be returned by `getProcedures` method?

I assume procedure overloading is forbidden in Oracle, am I right?

Comment: procedures can be overloaded, in which case you have to dive into the parameters to determine what's what.

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL Docs on overloaded subprograms http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99899

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle database allows you to create overloaded procedures but **only inside packages** but not standalone as stored procedures.

the GetProcedures method should return the procedures qualified with package and parameters.